# How can I run an executable from a CD when it doesn't have the executable bit set?

Tags: permissions, installation, cd, executable

A textbook I'm using came with a CD containing a few supplementary applications. To my pleasant surprise, it appears to include an installer for Linux.

The readme file on the CD provides the following installation instructions:

> PC: Linux
>
> 1. Double-click on the folder 'LINUX'
> 2. Double-click on the file 'INSTALL.BIN'
> 3. Follow instructions on screen.

But doing this just produces the following error message:

> Could not display "/media/BDH DE/linux/install.bin". The file is of an unknown type

Attempting to run the installer via the command line results in a permissions error:

```
ak@aux:~$ ls /media/BDH\ DE/
linux  os x  readme.txt  windows xp  windows xp - no java
ak@aux:~$ ls -l /media/BDH\ DE/linux/
total 41177
-rw-r--r-- 1 ak ak 42164549 2005-07-26 03:39 install.bin
ak@aux:~$ /media/BDH\ DE/linux/install.bin
bash: /media/BDH DE/linux/install.bin: Permission denied
```

While, to my disappointment, the message fails to inform me of *what* permissions I am lacking, a quick glance at the output of ls reveals that the installer has not been marked executable.

How do I run it?

---

The type of the file is:

```
ak@aux:~$ file /media/BDH\ DE/linux/install.bin
src/bdh-de/install.bin: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Comment: What kind of file is it? 'file /media/BDH\ DE/linux/install.bin
'?

Comment: Ah-ha. Bizarrely, it is actually just a text file with a `.bin` filename extension. How aggravatingly misleading.

Comment: Yeah - figured. So solved? Like if it's a shell script - you can 'bash /media/BDH\ DE/linux/install.bin' or something similar now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See what kind of file has been given a bin extension.

```
file $filename
```

If it's not binary data, it's text. So what program is to be used with this file?

```
head $filename
```

The first line might read `#!/bin/bash`. In that case run

```
bash $filename
```

to execute it. Or use whichever program for which the bin file was written, python, for example.

Comment: I still think how can i double click on the file and run it. It is still refusing to run if the file has '.bin' extension.

Answer (score 9):

If the problem is that CDROM was mounted 'noexec' you can remount it executable.

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/BDH\ DE/
```

Comment: yeah, right, very good, worked well.

Answer (score 4):

If its not a script/text but a binary:

For 64-bit programs:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./program.bin
```

For 32-bit programs:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./program.bin
```

Source:

*"To execute binaries, use /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./program.bin for 64-bit programs and /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./program.bin for 32-bit ones." – Comment from Lekensteyn on question https://askubuntu.com/a/17311/52853 Apr 13 2012*

Answer (score 1):

mount CDROM manually with umask=000, i.e.

```
sudo mount  -o umask=000 /dev/sdXY /mount_point
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of both:

```
bash -c <command>
```

or

```
sh -c <command>
```