# Is setting default mount options for udisks really not possible?

Tags: 10.10, usb-drive, automount, udisks

I want to mount usb drives with option flush (or sync).

I'm using Kubuntu 10.10 and as far as I understood *udisks* is responsible for the mount options. I've read various threads and two solutions are proposed:

1. edit `fstab` for every usb drive,
2. change default options in drives.c of the *udisks* package.

Is there really no decent way?

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't.

But you can try a workaround: using `udev` rules to override the `udisks` options by creating your own `/etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules` file; for details see [this great Archlinux site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Mount_under_.2Fmedia.3B_use_partition_label_if_present).

Comment: Should I create that file `11-media-by-label-auto-mount.rules`? I have only the `70-persistent-cd.rules` and `70-persistent-net.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.

Comment: Answered at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61448/how-to-configure-to-record-data-to-pendrive-instantly

Answer (score 2):

The ability to modify the allowed and default mount options is now available in [udisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/) as of version 2.9.0.
See the documentation [here](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) for how to configure default and allowed mount options.

I needed this functionality in order tweak the default Btrfs mount options.
Since 2.9.0 isn't shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 I also wrote up a tutorial on how to install it from source on Ubuntu 18.04 [here](https://www.jwillikers.com/install-udisks2-from-source) for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a promising workaround: [udisks-glue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/udisks-glue.1.html). See the man page for it's configuration file: [udisks-glue.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/udisks-glue.conf.5.html). I haven't tried it yet, but it may well be solution. It accepts mount options, but also a "post_mount_command".