# How do I set up the permissions on an automounted USB drive in 11.04

Tags: 11.04

Under 10.04 it was possible to use the gconf-editor system/storage setting to specify the default permissions for vfat and ntfs file systems when a USB drive was mounted. That seems to be missing in 11.04 in gconf-editor and dconf-editor. The automount gives no permissions to other users and groups to access the files and programs such as MediaTomb can not access files on a USB drive unless I format it in ext3.

How can I change the permissions at or after mounting - any change does not seem to be sticky on a ntfs or fat32 USB drive.

Comment: This question is of help http://askubuntu.com/questions/39552/nautilus-automount-controlling-gid-uid-mode-bits ?

Answer (score 2):

NTFS and FAT do not store permissions, so they are faked, making it look like you ( the person logged into the console ) own and can access the files, but not other users.  If you add an entry to /etc/fstab, you can specify the umask option and set whatever permissions you want.

Answer (score 0):

you should edit the /etc/fstab file and create a specific line for the device you want, more info can be found here: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html