# How can I execute a file without execute permissions?

Tags: permissions, executable

How can I execute a file without giving myself execute permissions (with `chmod u+x`) for it?

If I try and tick the 'Allow executing file as program' checkmark, the checkmark is immediately removed.

Comment: Similar: [How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83862/21471) at Unix

Comment: isn't the whole point of file permissions so that this DOESN'T happen? :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Check file ownership

**Please do this before anything further (unless you are sure you own the file).**

Check and make sure that you own the file which you are trying to execute with one of the following methods.

#### Graphical

1. Right click the file.
2. Click 'Properties'.
3. Click the 'Permissions' tab.
4. Ensure that the 'Owner' field says your username. If it doesn't see "Change file ownership" below

#### Command Line

1. Execute this command in a terminal

   ```
    [ ! -O "/path/to/file" ] && echo "You don't own the file"
   ```
2. If it prints "`You don't own the file`", see "Change file ownership" below.

### Change file ownership

Execute this command in a terminal

```
sudo chown $USER:$(id -gn $USER) "/path/to/file"
```

---

### Executable Files

An answer I found from a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition#comment145001_17311) by [Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn) on an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17311/176889) for a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/11840/176889) about `chmod` on NTFS partitions which I think deserves it's own question and answer, full credit to Lekensteyn.

Use this command for executable files (substituting `/path/to/executable` with the correct path):

- 64 bit executable files:

  ```
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/executable
  ```
- 32 bit executable files:

  ```
   /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /path/to/executable
  ```

If the above doesn't work (or raises file not found errors), try using this before the above command

```
cd "$(dirname /path/to/executable)"
```

All the above commands **will not** work for text based scripts (Bash, Python, Perl, etc.), see below.

#### Check if a program is 64 or 32 bit

Use this command to find out if a executable is 32 (`x86`) or 64 (`x86-64`) bit

```
objdump -f "$file" | grep '^architecture' | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's/architecture: //'
```

If it says `i386:x86-64`, then it's 64 bit. If it says `i386` only, then it's 32 bit.

---

### Scripts

For text based scripts (Bash, Python, Perl, etc.), you should use the command specified in the first `#!` line in the file.

For example, if the first line of the file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

then run these commands in a terminal (substituting `/path/to/file` with the correct path)

```
cd "$(dirname /path/to/file)"       # Not strictly necessary, see section below

# Replace '/usr/bin/env python3' with the first line without the front #!
/usr/bin/env python3 /path/to/file  # Use './file' if you want
```

---

### Java `.jar` files

For Java executable jar's, you can simply use these commands (substituting `/path/to/jar` with the correct path):

```
cd "$(dirname /path/to/jar)"   # Not strictly necessary, see section below
java -jar /path/to/jar
```

---

#### When you don't need `cd "$(dirname /path/to/file)"`

These are possible circumstances where you wont need to use `cd "$(dirname /path/to/file)"` before running the program with any method: If at least one is true, you wont need `cd` first.

- The program doesn't perform any file operations itself (example: it only uses `apt-get`)
- The program uses `cd` (or equivalent) to change to an absolute path before doing any file operations (example: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`)
- The program doesn't reference any relative paths (paths starting with `./` or starting with no slash)

If unsure, add `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` (or equivalent) to the top of the script (if applicable) or use `cd "$(dirname /path/to/file)"` anyway.

Comment: Anyone who wants to script this and make it to cover all the possibilities (if you use MS filesystems *a lot*) is welcome to. I might do it myself, but don't count on it. (+1 this comment if you want this, enough support and I might do it)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a shell script, you can "source" it from another shell script, i.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script runs another script indirectly, by sucking in its contents and evaluating inline:

source /path/to/script/which/lost/its/exec/flag "$@"
```

---

The "$@" appends the command line parameters, if needed.

Having said that, this is probably not the best solution for the underlying problem, but we don't know enough about that problem to offer alternatives.

Comment: I don't see how this is particularly different from `bash script $@`

Comment: It's not fundamentally different in operation.  Most likely I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve -- I assumed that you wanted a point-and-click way to execute a script that is (for whatever reason) not executable.  "Make one that's executable and have it source the other" is one solution to that problem.  If that's the wrong problem... well :)