# Unable to change execute permissions of .sh file

Tags: installation, permissions, jdk, execute-command

I'm out with a new problem. I've downloaded a `jdk7.sh` file. Now I'm unable to change the permission of the file to allow executing the file as a program. I mark the check box and again it disappears.

Comment: Is it on an NTFS partition? Where did you get this file from?

Comment: Specifically, please see the "Scripts" section of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/354343). To summarize for the case of your specific file: Assuming your file is named properly, `sh jdk7.sh` will run it normally and `sudo sh jdk7.sh` will run it as root (which might be necessary if its purpose is to create a  systemwide installation of the Java Development Kit, accessible to all users). If the file starts with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`, run `bash jdk7.sh` or `sudo bash jdk7.sh`. Note, the sourcing method in [the other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/359241) is *not* equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The check boxes would be dis-appearing because you don't have appropriate permission as well as ownership to the file.. Try to make executable with the help of `sudo` command.

**Try to change it by command line**

- Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Then reach to the `jdk7.sh` file.

  ```
  cd /home/gurung/Downloads
  ```

  if your file is locates in `/home/gurung/Downloads` or change accordingly.
- Then execute following commands to make it executable:

  ```
  sudo chmod +x jdk7.sh
  ```

  if your file name is `jdk7.sh` or replace the file name with the original one.

That's it.. :)

Comment: The actual problem is how to solve the issue.. Not finding different ways..