# How to run Code::Blocks from a USB Flash Drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive, code-blocks

I have been using Code::Blocks IDE for quite some time, and I have had no problems with it until now. I have recently decided to move almost all of my programs onto a USB for portability. Eclipse seems to work very well with creating it's workspace on the USB, but Code::Blocks keeps spitting out errors.  I can't for the life of me find a solution to my problem, so I hoped you could help me out.  Here's the error:

```
sh: 1: /media/luke/LUKESUSB/ProgrammingCPlusPlus/I like pi/bin/debug/I like pi: Permission denied
```

I have tried running the `sudo chmod -x` command multiple times on almost all the files in the folders to no avail.  The code for "I like pi" is just the default "Hello World" code that the program generates when you make a new console project. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the edit...  (This is my first question on askUbuntu btw.)

Comment: I couldn't find the download link for the portable version, are you sure it's on that page?

Comment: My bad, I though that debian packages pointing to `Home / Binaries / 13.12 / Linux (32bit)` in SourceForge could be portable. But they are .deb inside. Sorry for that Bubba3033.

Comment: I think it is related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/23128/how-do-i-execute-a-file-from-a-fat-usb-drive or may be this as permanent solution  https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/