# Cannot execute files on mounted file systems

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, permissions, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
>   [Trying to make file executable on USB, but the permission doesn't “stick”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23108/trying-to-make-file-executable-on-usb-but-the-permission-doesnt-stick)

I have a fat32 file system, which i mount from the gui file browser in 11.10, i can create and edit and save files in the mounted partition but I cannot set the execute bit in it.
i tries chmod +x but that also has no effect even when i do it as root.
It seems that execute permission is being turned off on all files by default on mount from GUI.
Is there a way to turn it on so that every time I mount i can execute files