# Why won't it allow me to change the access for disk games

Tags: permissions, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run an executable from a CD when it doesn't have the executable bit set?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22778/how-can-i-run-an-executable-from-a-cd-when-it-doesnt-have-the-executable-bit-se)

I now have Ubuntu LTS and any time I try to install a game using a disk it says mark as execute, and I do, but for some reason it says "Sorry, could not change the permissions of "Setup.exe": Error setting permissions: Read-only file system".

Is there any way of changing this?

Comment: You need to add some more detail to your question here, like which LTS are you talking about here? 10.04 or 12.04 Alpha?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Executables of `.exe` extensions do not work on Linux systems unless you are using a Windows-compatibility-layer/emulation software like [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/). And even then you cannot be 100% sure if the Windows software/game will be installable and runnable on Linux. You can check the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/) to see a list of Windows software and how much they are supported by Wine on Linux.

For information on changing the permissions of other partitions (the way they are mounted) and such, take a look at this question - [How to change permissions to the other drives in a hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk)

Comment: From the questions it seems that leviyoung2 is already using Wine, otherwise no message complaining about file being not marked as executable would appear.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't provide much info and I wasn't sure, so just thought I should provide the info, plus might be useful for other people who end up here trying to install `.exe` files. Thanks for pointing it out to me anyways :)