# How to run Doom3 BFG executable?

Tags: games, executable

I installed Doom3 BFG edition the way it said over [here](https://github.com/RobertBeckebans/RBDOOM-3-BFG/blob/master/README.txt).
The whole procedure was carried out as instructed.

When I double clicked the executable file, my computer didn’t know how to open it so nautilus searched for an app on the Internet and suggested to download pypar2, I downloaded it opened the executable file again and PyPar2 gave me options to create something; and I did it.

I still cannot play the game.

I’m running Edubuntu 12.10, and the directory is created in an NTFS formatted drive.

P.S. Its a fresh new Edubuntu installation, I haven’t installed any updates yet.

Comment: what kind of file is it? did you try to make it executable? `chmod +x my.file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that NTFS formatted drives do not support executable files. As stated [here](http://www.sinarpelangi.com/enable-setting-executable-permission-of-files-oat-ntfs-partition/):

> Setting executable permission of any files at ntfs partition on Linux is almost impossible.

The solutions I've seen so far are very hacky and I wouldn't recommend them unless you know what you are doing.

An easy workaround would be to move the whole game files to an `ext4` file system, for example, create a `Games` directory in your home directory, move the Doom3 BFG files there and make the executable files executable again:

```
$ chmod +x ~/Games/Doom3BFG/myExecutable
```

After that you should be able to run the file by double clicking it or run from command line with

```
$ ~/Games/Doom3BFG/myExecutable
```

If you prefer the more hacky way and want to run it only from your NTFS file system, you should read on the following threads:

- [Can't set permissions for files on an NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/5069/94697)
- [Enable Setting Executable Permission of Files at NTFS Partition](http://www.sinarpelangi.com/enable-setting-executable-permission-of-files-oat-ntfs-partition/)
- [How can I run an executable from a CD when it doesn't have the executable bit set?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22778/94697)

Comment: So thats the problem... Thanks bro, didnt know you couldnt run executables from an ntfs drive.
I may try the 'hacky' process.. :|
Or, I may formate a pendrive ext4 and run from there... Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, you can format the drive ext4, but you wont be able to read ext4 file systems with windows.

Comment: That's not so, you can read ext4 with windows using ext2fsd. http://www.ext2fsd.com/ for more info and http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/latest/download?source=files to download. Also, http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/