# Running games from any other directory then DESKTOP? (my target is CD and SD card)

Tags: games

Here is download link to the game I created https://www.sendspace.com/file/d8wxsr

Here is the video of the problem:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjIajd4ZFuY

In short I want to be able to run the game from CD rom or SD card just by double clicking it. But I have a problem UBUNUTU does not allow executing the game from any other FOLDER then the the DESKTOP.

Comment: Termhn@ Look at the video what I tried with your advice and failed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf-UujaR118&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

OK if you want to burn the CD you should do this:

1. In Ubuntu, put the 'fps6' folder on your desktop
2. Go into terminal and do:

   `cd ~/Desktop/fps6`

   `sudo chmod +x runner`
3. Open "Brasero" and click "New Data Project" then click the "+" in the top left. Select the 'runner' and 'assets' from inside 'fps6' folder *on your desktop* that you just `chmod`'d
4. Select the CD you want to burn to.
5. Click the "Burn" button in bottom right.

UPDATE: you could try doing this

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/Linuxgame
```

Comment: If you look at the video I tried this chmod thing but it failed. Lets say UBUNTU shows this path to the file: /media/jack/WinXP/fps6. The name of the executable file: runner.

So how do I setup the chmod command?

Comment: I believe it would be sudo chmod +x /media/jack/WinXP/fps6/runner

Comment: I just watched your video and updated my answer... @UbuntuGameLover

Comment: WinXP is actually a separate partition of drive, which does contain Windows XP. As I believed if it would run from a seperate partition it should run from all devices.  Ok gksudo I have not tried yet. I am very tired now but I will let you know later

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but the fact that it is formatted in NTFS (windows) might have something to do with it... I would try running it somewhere else like whatever media you want to use it on in the end.

Comment: You are suggesting like burn it on a cd and test it?

Comment: Yeah or an sd card or whatever else... Or just put it in a different folder within your ubuntu partition to start with.

Comment: Can you see what went wrong? This I done so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf-UujaR118&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The CD you're using is a read-only file system. That means you can't change anything on it once you burn it. Therefore, the file must have the executable bit *before* you burn the CD. Do the `sudo chmod +x /path/to/runner` on the file while it's on your desktop and then burn that file (that you chmod'd) onto the CD. Or just use an SD card or USB stick, in which case you'll have a read/write filesystem.. I'm still confused why you want to use a CD.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again I will test later again. So if I want to burn it on the CD how should I do it and which program? Cause I actually burned file in windows I never done it in UBUNTU.

Comment: Just updated my answer with new instructions

Comment: Something went wrong I think: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydqybNYR6JM&list=UUIR30ZP3s07epFu4mhixumQ     Did I missed something? I did followed all instructions you gave?

Comment: Yeah, you followed the instructions correctly. I guess burning it to a CD automatically removes the executable bit... I don't know if there's any way to do that. I do believe if you put it on an SD card it would work though.

Comment: I do need a protected media, otherwise it's useless to make a quality game. Then only free to play games are able to be made for linux if you cant place them on protected media like a CD. But I will try a SD card.

Comment: Um.... no? Barely anyone actually buys a disk for a game anyway, you download it off some store like Steam. If you want to distribute your game then do it digitally especially as an indie developer.

Comment: Perhaps I am to old fashioned here, But I am sure there are still a tons of games which only come on disk. Only their demo's are download but actual game is mostly on CD for example GTA IV.

Comment: No, GTA IV has a digital version too http://store.steampowered.com/app/12210/ The only place where anyone actually buys a disk for a game anymore is the console market, and even that is declining. There's no way to target a DVD as your primary media to distribute as an indie dev. Where are you going to get the funding to mass manufacture the disks and boxes etc?

Comment: I found this topic perhaps can you find the possible solution for running games from CD http://askubuntu.com/questions/22778/how-can-i-run-an-executable-from-a-cd-when-it-doesnt-have-the-executable-bit-se

Comment: Yes I saw that topic too... the problem is I don't think it's a normal executable... you could try doing this though (updated answer)